# How to record user activity - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

I'm currently running Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise and would like to know the following:

- Which pages each user has accessed over the last X Days
- How much time each user has spent on each page (can't average, I need to know per user)

It is like a Google Analytics, but at a "user" level. Any clues on how to do that?

I searched a lot stackoverflow and found nothing. Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology.

Comment: Is that a programing question? Else, you should use http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Under the site collection administration "popularity and search report". You can find some of the information.

According to MSDN blog ***"Due to less than optimal performance running service at scale in large enterprises, web analytics has been discontinued and is not available in SharePoint 2013."*** 
Web analytics was available in 2010.

If allowed you can choose Google analytics, its just java script reference , add it in your default master page

Comment: Just be sure you don't capture/store user display names if you use GA - it is technically against their Terms of Service to capture any PII. That being said, you supposedly are allowed to capture user IDs that do not contain PII, which you can then cross-reference back to your own identity management system (AD, etc). Reference: http://davidsimpson.me/2013/10/17/identifying-your-users-in-google-analytics-while-complying-with-section-7-of-the-terms-of-service/

Answer (score 0):

**Definitely not web analytics**, but user specific usage reporting based on sessions.

Assuming that this is cleared by your legal department (which at least in the EU most likely would not happen), what you need is a simple database with page views (with session info) and each action time stamped.

This would then be reported per user to contain a list of sessions, that each have a list of pages and calculate the time between first and last interaction per session.